# Can you name an instance the same as its constructor name?

Tags: javascript, constructor, singleton, instance

Can you name an instance the same as its constructor name?

```
var myFunc = new function myFunc(){};
```

?

As it seems, this replaces the Function Object with the new instance... which means this is a good Singleton.

I haven't seen anyone using this, so I guess, there are downsides to this that I am unaware of...

Any thoughts?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 If you're not a JS guy, it doesn't matter if it looks strange to you as much... If it looked weird to a JS developer, then I would care more

Comment: Actually it does. Because I am here to learn...

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Then this is a lesson?

Comment: What's the point of the second `myFunc` there? You can just as easily create a single instance of a class by saying `var myFunc = new function() { ... }`.

Comment: The lesson being my assumption is correct that it indeed does look strange?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I did miss the fact that the constructor was defined inline, that doesn't make a lot of sense, I concur

Comment: It could be implemented as funciton myFunc(){}   var myFunc = new myFunc(). the idea id to create a singleton. and is this a good implantation of one.

Comment: Well... you could implement a lot of things in javascript. Doesn't make it a good idea ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I'm curious: Would you still find it weird if the function wasn't named?  `var myFunc = new function() {...}`

Comment: Not really. That makes sense to me (syntax wise)`. Still don't see why on earth you want to do that though.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I do agree, sorry about the misunderstanding earlier, you helped me improve my answer a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES...

However, it does look weird that you're creating a named function but never refer to it by name.

The more common pattern(s) I've seen are

```
function MyClass(){
    this.val = 5;
};
MyClass.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return this.val;
}
MyClass = new MyClass();
```

But when people do that I wonder why they don't just use a literal object

```
var MyClass = {
    val: 5,
    getValue: function() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

And I would even prefer to use the module pattern here

```
var MyClass = (function(){
    var val = 5;
    return {
        getValue: function() {
            return val;
        }
    };     
})();
```

**Disclaimer**

Now whether the singleton pattern should be used, that's another question (to which the answer is NO if you care about testing, dependency management, maintainability, readability)

- http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337
- [Why implementing a Singleton pattern in Java code is (sometimes) considered an anti-pattern in Java world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292109/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern-in-java-world-sometimes)

Comment: What is the use of `new function`?

Comment: I didn't notice that part, that is surely a bit weird, let me fix the answer

Comment: If you try to overwrite MyClass->val after "MyClass = new MyClass()" what happens?

Comment: @KrisGeorgiev In all but the last case, you are overwriting the `val` property of `MyClass` (the object, not the class that is not the cosntructor that is notreachable anymore). In the last example, it's creating a new property on the object. I'm not sure what the point of your question is...

Answer (score 0):

> As it seems, this replaces the Function Object with the new instance

No, it  does not replace anything. The name of a *function expression* (that's what you have) is only accessible inside the function itself, not outside of it. It would be exactly the same as if you omit the name:

```
 var myFunc = new function(){};
```

In general, if you don't want certain symbols accessible, just don't make them global. Define those symbols inside a function and just return whatever you want to make accessible, e.g:

```
var myobj = (function() {
    function Foo() {};
    // do whatever
    return new Foo();
}());
```

However, if you just want to create a single object, it is often easier to use an *object literal*:

```
var myobj = {};
```

There is no reason to use a constructor function if you only want to create a single instance from it. If you want to establish inheritance, you can use [`Object.create` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: Obviously this could be possible, but for readability reasons, you do not want to declare the instance the same place as the constructor this might be a good way to go about it...

Comment: The variable does shadow the named function, doesn't it?

Comment: @Juan: As I said, a named function expression does not create a symbol with that name in the enclosing scope. The name is only available inside the function. Try `var foo = function bar() {}; alert(bar);`.

Comment: I mean an example like what the OP has... where the variable and function names are the same. Something like `(function() {    console.log("Before", MyFun);
    var MyFun = new function MyFun() {};
    console.log("After", MyFun);  
})()`, the output is `Before undefined` followed by `After MyFun {} `  http://jsfiddle.net/WWLJ7/

Comment: @Juan: http://jsfiddle.net/WWLJ7/1/ ... the name of the function is not available in the enclosing scope. The function object will never be assigned to `MyFun` at any point.

Comment: @FelixKling But in your example, you're not creating a name conflict ("where the variable and function names are the same"), which would create the "shadowing". I guess I don't understand what you're saying...

Comment: @Juan: By choosing two different names `A` (variable) and `B` (function), I can show that there never is a conflict or shadowing because symbol `B` will never be created. The name you give to the function is completely irrelevant.