# Singleton: How does static variable $instance store data

Tags: php, design-patterns, static, singleton

I've got a comprehension question:

The singleton design pattern uses a static function call like Singleton::getInstance() and in this function it uses static variables like self::$_instance.

According to the definition, static functions and variables are independent of any concrete instances and are evoked each time just for the purpose of it's particular call. How then is it possible, that any value can be stored in such quasi-abstract and each-time-new-created 'objects'?

Hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 3):

Static property is similar to global variable. Difference only of its visibilities. Global variable can changed by everybody as public static property, but private or protected static property has less visibility.

Imaginate that class is actually an object which created when defined and could exists only in one instance. Static properties and methods are properties and methods of this "object". That is why many people does not understand differnce between regular class with static members and singleton.

[Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), [singleton pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton)

Comment: so a class itself can be seen as (instantiated) object per se? this is quite confusing, as a class per definitionem should be just a 'template' for instances derived from it.

Answer (score 2):

The Singleton design [(anti-)pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292142/1446005) allows to make sure there is at most one instance created.

The property is static, therefore it can be accessed from a static method. However the underlying object is a real, live instance. From a static method, you cannot use `$this`, but you can refer to any already-instanciated object, which `self::$_instance` happens to be)

```php
class SingletonClass {

    private static $_instance;
    private $_someProperty;

    public static function getSomeProperty() {
        return self::$_instance->_someProperty; // allowed, self::$_instance is static, but a real object nonetheless
    }

}
```

Comment: it's no a singleton, as your __construct method still open.

Answer (score -1):

Three things make the class Singleton or else it will a normal class.

1. Static variable
2. Static method
3. Private constructor

Probably you have created a class for counter functionality, Singleton is like the same.

Comment: The class doesn't need to have all of this, you can use dependency injection and specify the lifetime of the object that the injector only return the same instance of the class. This is also a singleton.