# Sample application for implementation of Guava Cache and Spring for Database caching

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava, database-caching

Firstly I am totally new to Guava cache and Spring as well, I had searched more 50 sites but could not get, what I was looking for. I am searching for implementation of guava cache for caching database values using spring.

Also, previously I had implemented `Ehcache` but had the following issues:

1. It does not work with `static` (as per my findings).
2. `@Cacheable` is not working when the cacheable method is called via non-bean class instance[here's the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28215268/2749470).
3. It requires a every time configuration of new cache (`ehcache.xml`). etc were problems.

So now I am looking for a solution which can over come above hurdles via `guava cache` if any one could provide a configuration + implementation example with spring than it be a ton help to me. Also if any other way is their for caching data from DB than please let me know (other than manual cache implementation like `list`,`hashmap` etc).

Comment: Please put together a minimal example, with the given amount of information it's going to be really hard to help you. Do you have a properly working Spring Application context?

Comment: Have you gone trough the manual http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html ?

Comment: @reto yes, I have proper working spring-application -context.xml with `hikari-cp` and currently with `ehcache` m using `namedjdbcparameterstemplate`

Comment: Does the answer that is given to the question that you linked make sense? Do you understand the proxies in Spring?

Comment: @reto yes I had gone through it roughly but later came know above mentioned bullet issues

Comment: @reto yes that's why I had mentioned but it does has a solution rather it has criticism in that answer and one more thing it does not works with thread one more [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28228865/2749470) I neeed to implement thread as well in my application

Comment: I answered another question with a full example of how to setup Guava caching in spring here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable/31926759#31926759