# Instance of object without defining class

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have used the following method to define instances of objects without defining classes :

```js
var obj = new function () {
  this.x = 25;                // Public variable
  var y = 10;                 // Private variable

  this.print = function () {  // Public function
    alert( this.x + y );    
  }
}

obj.print();
```

Does this have any demerits as compared to other Module patterns ? ( For JSLint says `odd construct at line 1` )

Comment: what's the point to create only one instance without opportunity to create more?

Comment: The code is part of my game http://meghprkh.github.io/samehue/ where classes like Manager, Input Manager, Display Manager are created only once but they help segregate the code into sort of namespaces.

Comment: general practice is to use self executing functions for this

Comment: Sounds like what you actually need is a singleton  http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

Comment: @KirillPisarev Can you please give an example as how it can be used in my case ? I tried to read http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write .

Comment: @atmd Singleton requires a lot of boilerplate. For example you have to redeclare the public variables and functions at the end while this method requires only adding `this` to the public variables

Comment: It may require more code, but it's a well used pattern for a reason. Also, using the Function constructor is a big perf hit

Comment: @atmd I dont think this is a function constructor that I am using. See this  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_function_constructors.htm . This is perhaps a new Module pattern I am talking about. (I use `function` and not `Function` )

Comment: What if I use the revealing module pattern and it requires access to another object defined by another script file? Will it raise any error?

Comment: @user2368055 I dont understand stivlo's answer's relation with this question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using this method (that I can think of). The problem is it very risky.

What happens if you forget to write `new`. This won't throw any error as it is a valid assignment. In such case not only your variable `obj` will get messed up (it will become a 'function') but also your global scope will get corrupted if the function is executed. If the function is executed then `this` inside the function points to global scope and all the bindings are done to the global scope. You definitely don't want to do that.

Comment: Why is this Question on hold? I feel it is quite clear what OP is asking.

Comment: I feel it is clear what I am asking. Except that earlier it was a little misworded (I did not know that they were called module patterns) due to which  the answer by @user2368055 is a little irrelevant now

Comment: @AnuragPeshne your comment is good and should be converted to answer.

Comment: Can the people keeping this question on hold please elaborate their reason as to what is unclear?

Comment: @MeghParikh thanks but I'm sure there are also other better reasons to not to make objects that way. We should reopen this question so that others can contribute. Besides I'm sure many newbies will have the same doubt. Please rephrase the question in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a aggregated scopes, use Self-Executing Anonymous Functions :

```
var obj = (function () {
  var y = 10;                 // Private variable

  return {
    x: 25,                    // Public variable

    print: function () {      // Public function
      alert( this.x + y );    
    }
  }
})();

obj.print();
```

The differencies between self-executing anonymous functions and creating instance of anonymous class is only in ideology. SEAF is for once and class is for multiple usage. BTW actually the same thing happens in both times. When you call `new` to the function, it returns a new object with the properties of `this`, it's the same we can see in SEAF.

Comment: As i asked before what are the merits of this method over mine?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `print` directly on the object (with `this.print`) you use some memory to store the property (here method) for each object (instantiation of your class). When you define it on the prototype, all the instances will share the same property (so the same memory).

You will also have some troubles to use [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

If you only want one instance of your "class", you certainly should use a pattern singleton. But for a more powerful solution I would suggest you to try a framework implementing a dependency injection component because [singleton is almost an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern). You can find an example of this kind of framework following the link in my profile (you cannot use it without a node.js server but it is a nice example).

Finally, you may define your class like the following:

```js
var Class = function() {
  this._x = 25;                // Public variable
  this._y = 10;               // Private variable
}

Class.prototype.print = function() {
  alert(this._x + this._y); 
}

Object.defineProperty(Class.prototype, 'x', {
    get: function() { return this._x; }
});

var obj = new Class();
obj.print();

alert(obj.x);
alert(obj.y);
```

Comment: How is `y` a private variable? Try adding `alert(obj._y)` to the end.

Comment: There is no clean and easy way to define a private property. I personally use _ to specify a private property and set an accessor on it to define its accessibility. But of course, this won't ensure that someone use the _ property instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: I think that the thing about memory also occurs in self-executing anonymous functions but I am unsure about your method (though I cant use it due to the amount of boilerplate involved)

Comment: I just gave you what I thought are good practices to do OOP in javascript (and generally) today. Of course, changing this in a big project can require a lot of time! And yes, the self-executing anonymous function will have the same behaviour for memory as your own solution.