# Not able to access object in python while creating object of other class defined in some other file

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, object, python-import

I have a directory structure like this:

```
home/
    main.py

    lib/
       mylib/
            Textfile_Class.py
            Excelfile_Class.py
            globals.py   (has all the global variables declared here)
            functions.py
```

I created an object of `Textfile_class` in `main.py` using 
`txt = TEXT(file)`.

Now, I want to use this variable `txt`  during creating object of `Excelfile_Class` for some operations (eg, if the value of a variable in `txt` object is 5, then do certain action in `Excelfile_Class )`

In `Excelfile_Class`, I am also importing all the global variables. String variables are accessible there but I dont know why this object `txt` is not accessible there. Wherever I am refering to `txt` in `Excelfile_Class`(`self.line_count = txt.count`), I am getting below error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'`

Please help me to know why this is happening even though I have defined all the variables in a seperate file and importing those in all the files.

Eg:
main.py

```
path = os.path.abspath('./lib')
sys.path.insert(0, path)

from mylib.Textfile_class import * 
from mylib.Excelfile_Class import *
from mylib.globals import *
from mylib.functions import *

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    txt = TEXT(file)
    xcel = EXCEL(file)
```

Eg globals.py

```
global txt, xcel
txt=None
xcel=None
```

Eg Textfile_class.py

```
from globals import *
class TEXT:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.count = 0
        with open(filename) as fp:
            for line in fp:
                self.count = self.count + 1`
```

Eg Excelfile_Class.py

```
from globals import *

class EXCEL:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.line_count = 0
        self.operation(filename)

    def operation(self, file):
        self.line_count = txt.count 
        if self.line_count:
            self.some_operation()
        else:
            self.other_operation()
```

Comment: Can you provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)? Otherwise the best we can do is guess as to the correct answer. The one thing that I *do* know is that in `Excelfile_Class` when you use `txt` it's `None`, instead of whatever you expect it to be. That's why you're getting the `AttributeError`

Comment: @WayneWerner I have provided a small version of my code, please help now.

Comment: Considering the string "no_of_lines_in_file" does not appear anywhere in the code you've posted, it'll be very difficult to determine where that error comes from and what it means...

Comment: @twalberg Corrected the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a value to a variable name inside a function, you're not working with the global version of the variable any more, instead you have a completely new variable.

You have to use `global` keyword **inside** the function to indicate you're working with a global variable.

From Python Doc FAQ

> **What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?**
>
> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.
>
> [Read more...](http://In%20Python,%20variables%20that%20are%20only%20referenced%20inside%20a%20function%20are%20implicitly%20global.%20If%20a%20variable%20is%20assigned%20a%20new%20value%20anywhere%20within%20the%20function%E2%80%99s%20body,%20it%E2%80%99s%20assumed%20to%20be%20a%20local.%20If%20a%20variable%20is%20ever%20assigned%20a%20new%20value%20inside%20the%20function,%20the%20variable%20is%20implicitly%20local,%20and%20you%20need%20to%20explicitly%20declare%20it%20as%20%E2%80%98global%E2%80%99.)

Example:

```
x = None                # x is momdule-level global variable

def local():
    x = 5               # assign 5 to x, here x is a new variable, global x is not affected.

def glob():
    global x            # indicate we'll working with the global x.
    x = 5               # this affect the global variable.

def print_global():
    print(x)            # Just print the global variable.

local()                 
print_global()          # Prints None
glob()
print_global()          # Prints 5
```

So, every time you refer to `txt` inside a function, you have to tell the context you'll be working with the global version of `txt`.

### Other thing can be happening!

Python is interpreted, that means it execute the code line by line, if in the others modules (not in the main module) you have code trying to access txt before some value be assigned

```
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    txt = TEXT(file)
```

, then you'll get the same error.

### A recommendation:

Try to avoid the use of global variables, you already know that isn't a good practice and it leads to unestable code.

If your problem is that you want to `txt` and `xcel` to be available at any time anywhere, you could use the pattern [Singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) **(warning, Singleton is considered an anti-pattern [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern))**

I will post an example for you, but before I will encorage you to redesign your program, I ensure you it will be a good exercise!

**Singleton example:**  (again this is an anti-pattern, but I preffer it to nude global variables).

```
class Globals(object):

    __instance = None

    def __init__(self):

        class wrapped_class:
            def __init__(self):
                self.txt = None
                self.excel = None

        if (Globals.__instance is None):
            Globals.__instance = wrapped_class()

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        return getattr(self.__instance, attrname)

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        setattr(self.__instance, attrname, value)

glob = Globals()            # Since __instance is None this will instantiate wrapped_class and save the reference in __instance
glob.txt = "Txt example"    # Modify the txt attribute of __instance. 
glob_1 = Globals()          # Since __instance is not None it stays as it is.

print(glob.txt)             # Prints  "Txt example"
print(glob_1.txt)           # Prints  "Txt example"
```

Comment: I did the changes for global suggested by you, but still its not working. And there is no such case as you mentioned below under heading "other thing can be happening!" Can you please help further?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to tell where your problem is without having the code or the stack trace but I would strongly advice that you read some documentation about Python best practices, the use of global variables and naming conventions. This by itself might solve your issues.
Naming conventions might sound silly but those things and other syntax-related choices do matter in python.

Also, you seem to be missing `__init__.py` file in your module which may or may not be important depending of the python version you are using.

Here are a few links to get you started:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references
- http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php
- http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.be/2012/05/variable-scope.html
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it happened like that. If anyone knows they can tell.

The problem got resolved when I used the method given in [Using global variables between files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python).

So, finally I put all the global variables in a function in `globals.py` and instantiated that once in `main.py`. Then, I used `from mylib import globals` and referenced the global variables inside the classes as `globals.txt` and it worked fine.