# How to limit class object in C++

Tags: c++, object, design-patterns, singleton

I want limit object that can construct (2 more object)
Singleton Pattern is similar this solution but only useful to only one object.

I need your help.
HELP..

Comment: And if you just create two objects? Is it really *necessary* to prevent more instances?

Comment: Note: the Singleton pattern is often considered an anti-pattern and you may want to rethink your design choices ([Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)).

Comment: I just create some instances to defined number. Every other is same to singleton pattern. Should I be rethink solution?


`static Singleton& getInstance(int i) { return inst[i]; }`
Does this solution has any problem?

Comment: What you're describing is known as Multiton pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern