# PHP: How to create function which will be accessible with :: (double colon, scope resolution) in another classes

Tags: php, scope-resolution

I´m trying to create a logging class which will be accessible in all Classes around the PHP app by

```
logger::log(something);
```

and this will add next row into my logfile (the part with inserting into file is easy for me). I saw the double colon in DIBI (database framework). It is cool, because I can use dibi::dataSource("") whereever I need. But don´t know how to do this in my application.

Right now I have something in some class (I have more similar classes in the app) like (shorted):

```
Class DoSomething {
  function runTests() {
    logger::log("Test started");
    // do the magic
    logger::log("It ends");
  }
}
```

In index.php I have something like:

```
// init
$app = new DoSomething;
$app->runTests();
...
```

And I would like to have in index.php some code, which will add the accessibility of logging function in class with "logger::log();". But don´t know how to do this. Can you please help me?

Maybe it can somehow work with "extends", but is there any easier solution?
I have tried to read - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php but still not sure, how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705976/when-should-i-use-static-methods may be worth a read.

Comment: What you're looking at is a *static* method. For all intents and purposes, it's nothing more than a normal global function. Read [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double colon allows access to static function and constants in a class.

Change your class method to:

```
static function runTests() {
...
```

and then call it like this

```
DoSomethin::runTests();
```

Comment: OK, I just changed the code and it works with static in run.php. But when i use  logger::log('something to log') in another Class/function. Than I get error:

Notice: Undefined variable: logger in ....Project.php on line 26

Can I change the logger variable to global or something?

Comment: Are you loading your `logger` class properly? You always need to `require/include` its file or configure autoloading.

Comment: I had an error there. Used another variable. Thank zou for help. It wokrs now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, what you are looking for is a static method.
This kind of method would allow you to call your function without instantiating an object beforehand (using `new Logger`)

To do that, your function should be declared as `public static`. Here's an example:

```
public static function test()
{
    // Method implementation
}
```

More documentation here : [php static functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-function-in-php/)