# Why use static methods in program.cs C#?

Tags: c#

I always knew that I have to use static methods but I wonder why?
As you can see below I have to make "MigrateDatabase" Static

```
using System;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MigrateDatabase();
        }

        private static void MigrateDatabase()
        {
          //.....
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: In this case it's because you can't call non static functions from static functions in this specific case.

Comment: You have to make it static _for this code_ but you don't have to make it static if you write the code differently.

Comment: `new Program().MigrateDatabase()` is my go to in such cases, since typing `static` every time is a pain.

Comment: @MathewHD: not really true: you can call non-static functions from static functions, if you have a reference to the object containing the method.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705976/when-should-i-use-static-methods/33706003

Comment: @MathewHD That's just not true.  You can absolutely call instance methods from static methods.  You just need to provide an instance when calling them method.  It's *super* common to call instance methods from static methods.  In fact I'd guess a large majority of static methods call an instance method.

Comment: I make all functions static that I want to call across my froms to make them independent from any instance variables.

Comment: I guess the duplicate is fne here, but it should be noted that it is not for c# but java.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just be clear, the only reason `MigrateDatabase` has to be static in this case is because you're calling it from a static method (`Main`). If instead `MigrateDatabase` was an instance method on a class, you could instantiate that class and call it

```
using System;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var migration = new Migration();
            migration.MigrateDatabase();
        }   
    }

    public class Migration
    {
        private void MigrateDatabase()
        {
          //.....
        }
    }
}
```

You could also put it as a instance method on `Program` if you're instantiating an instance of *that* class

```
using System;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.MigrateDatabase();
        }

        private void MigrateDatabase()
        {
          //.....
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: People: I'm happy for my answers to be edited with corrections, but please don't wholesale change it!