# If each 'transaction' is an object, how do you store the total cost of all transactions made?

Tags: java

Foreword: sorry for all the code, I know most of it is redundant for this question.

This class takes a description (size), a cost, and a quantity as arguments and returns the number of times the object was created (transaction_number), the total quantity specified for all the objects created (total_quantity), and (is supposed to) return the total cost of all the object created.

```
public class SalesTransaction
{
    private static int counter = 1;
    public final int transaction_number;
    private static int order_quantity = 0;
    public final int total_quantity;
    private static double temp_grand_total = 0;
    public final double grand_total;
    private String size;
    private double cost;
    private int quantity;

    public SalesTransaction(String size, double cost, int quantity)
    {   
        this.size = size;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;

        this.transaction_number = counter++;
        order_quantity += quantity;
        this.total_quantity = order_quantity;
        temp_grand_total += totalCostAfterTax(cost*quantity); // this is wrong!
        this.grand_total = temp_grand_total;
    }

    public static double discountAmount(int quantity, double cost)
    {
        double discount_amount = 0; 
        if (quantity > 20)
        {
            discount_amount = cost * 0.10;
        }   
        return discount_amount;
    }

    public static double totalCostBeforeTax(SalesTransaction temp)
    {
        double total_cost;
        int quantity = temp.quantity;
        double cost = temp.cost;
        total_cost = quantity * cost;
        double discount_amount = discountAmount(quantity, total_cost);
        total_cost = total_cost - discount_amount;
        return total_cost;
    }

    public static double totalCostAfterTax(double total_cost)
    {
        total_cost = total_cost * 1.15;
        return total_cost;
    }

    public static void printStats(SalesTransaction temp)
    {
        System.out.println("Transaction Number: " + temp.transaction_number);
        System.out.println("Size: " + temp.size);
        System.out.println("Cost Per Table: "+ temp.cost);
        System.out.println("Number of Tables: " + temp.quantity);
        System.out.println("Total Tables So Far: " + temp.total_quantity);
        double total_cost_before_tax = totalCostBeforeTax(temp);
        double discount_amount = discountAmount(temp.quantity, total_cost_before_tax);
        System.out.println("Discount: " + discount_amount);
        double total_cost_after_tax = totalCostAfterTax(total_cost_before_tax);
        temp.temp_grand_total = total_cost_after_tax;
        System.out.println("Cost for this transaction: " + total_cost_after_tax);
        System.out.println("Total cost: "+ temp.grand_total);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And this is just a tester class.

```
public class SalesTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SalesTransaction one = new SalesTransaction("Small", 10.0, 10);
        one.printStats(one);

        SalesTransaction two = new SalesTransaction("Medium", 20.0, 30);
        two.printStats(two);

        SalesTransaction three = new SalesTransaction("Large", 30.0, 40);
        three.printStats(three);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to store the grand_total. I tried doing it the same way I stored the total_quantity but I can see why that isn't working.

How can I keep track of the grand total of all the transactions (objects) so I can then print it out on the console?

I assume there's another way of expressing this in the constructor but I'm not sure how and I couldn't find any examples of this.

Comment: I would think of these as line items, and a transaction would be made up of a number of line items.

Comment: The properties of the transaction are exactly like line items. The purpose of this exercise is to practice some sort of bookkeeping skills I would imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a `static` field on your `SalesTransaction` class which holds the `grand_total`. A `static` variable is shared by all instances of a class.

```
private static double grandTotal = 0;
public SalesTransaction(double cost) {
    grandTotal += cost;
}
```

**However**, this has some disadvantages in the long run. It would mean you can't have transactions as members of different grand totals. This is why it's called the [singleton anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern).

A much better way to solve the problem is to make an additional class such as `TransactionGroup`, which contains `SalesTransaction` objects in a `List`, and sums together the costs when needed.

```
public class TransactionGroup {
    private List<SalesTransaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addTransaction(SalesTransaction st) {
        transactions.add(st);
    }
    public double getGrandTotal() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (SalesTransaction st : transactions) {
            sum += st.getCost();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is really interesting, I never thought about making a separate class to keep track. Thanks!