# Interface in .java throws error

Tags: java, android, class, interface, singleton

I am trying to **learn** how to create an `interface`. I have read different articles and seem to be missing some basic concept.

I want to create a class that when it is done doing something, it will notify any listening classes that it has finished. For example, I want to instantiate a version of `MySingletonClass` in my `MainActivity`. Have `MySingletonClass` do something from `MainActivity` and then when finished, call `someMethod` that has been *Overridden* in `MainActivity` to

But when I create my interface I get the error:

> Class is public, should be declared in a file named filename.java

**Here is the error on screen:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication;

public interface MySingletonInterface {
    void someMethod();

}

public class MySingletonClass {
    private static MySingletonClass ourInstance = new MySingletonClass();

    private MySingletonInterface msi;

    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private MySingletonClass() {
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        msi.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Is this the way I should be doing it? Is there some better best-practice? Again I am learning java/android.

I come from an iOS background and in iOS we have what is called a delegate pattern, it's a way for a class to notify another class that it has finished doing something. Is there something like that in Java?

Comment: Error message is quite clear. `MySingletonInterface` should be in `MySingletonInterface.java` and `MySingletonClass` in `MySingletonClass.java`.

Comment: Either remove the word `public`, or move the interface and class to separate suitably named files.

Comment: `MySingletonInterface` should be its own file. If it is only going to be used by `MySingletonClass` then it should really be marked private.

Comment: It's best if you put each class or interface in its own file.  The name of any public class or interface has to match the name of the file.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of having an interface? Couldn't I just `implements` MySingletonClass?

Comment: `public` means that every class should be able to access it, which means it needs to be in its own file - how else would other classes find it? If you intend to use the interface for this package only, don't use any access modifier keyword - simply remove `public`.

Comment: While it's a good exercise for learning Java, please see [Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12755539/5743988).

Comment: I come from an iOS background and in iOS we have what is called a delegate pattern, it's a way for a class to notify another class that it has finished doing something. Is there something like that in Java?

Comment: Yes, the delegate pattern can be used in Java. [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+delegate+pattern&oq=java+delegate+pattern&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5928j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Interface and class have to be in separate files.  I don't see what the interface is doing for you as written.

You're learning Java.  Forget about Singletons.  They aren't a good idea.

MySingletonInterface.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication;

public interface MySingletonInterface {
    void someMethod();

}
```

MySingletonClass.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication;

public class MySingletonClass implements MySingletonInterface {

    private static final MySingletonClass ourInstance = new MySingletonClass();

    private MySingletonClass() {}

    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        // Implement here
    }
}
```

Comment: Singletons aren't a good idea? Why? If I need one instance of an object, but I need to reference it in different activities, how do you do that?

Comment: Google has gone to great lengths to expunge Singletons from all their code.  You should do the same.  http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2007/07/google-singleton-detector-released.html

Comment: Read the link I gave you.  Global variables and bottlenecks are never good.  You may think you only need one, but the requirement is usually more imagination than fact.  Dependency injection solves it easily: Inject a reference into the objects that need it.