# One object for whole application life or one object per call + dispose

Tags: c#, static, member, idisposable

I have an IDisposable class A. I need to use an object of A inside another method M of class B. Method M is called multiple times (million times a day). Should I use local object of A inside M and dispose once done or should I declare class level static member inside B and dispose once application ends. 
Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: Why can't B take an A instance in its constructor and supply it to M as needed, and then B can destroy it when it's done with it?  An object is responsible for cleanup of resources it provides via public interface unless that interface is a factory method or a constructor, in which case the caller is responsible.

Comment: Each call to M is through new instance of B.

Comment: Sounds like singleton is appropriate here, assuming it's thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One object for the life of the application is a Singleton; while they are useful under specific circumstance, they are not generally a good idea. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern) for a detailed explanation of why.

Classes that implement `IDisposable` are best used within the confines of a `using` statement that will take care of disposing it for you.

The clear exception to this is when multiple calls to the disposable class will be needed in the context of a single business action -- and that action is too spread out to be wrapped in a `using` statement. In this case, wrapping all the calls into a second disposable class that has the first as a private member.  when the second class is disposed it should dispose of any private members that are disposable.

Comment: Calls to method M of class B originating from multiple instances of B.
Like below
B b = new B()
b.M()
I don;t see a point of making B disposable.

Comment: Another non-obvious case where a class that implements `IDisposable` should be held for the life of the application, and not used inside a `using` is `HttpClient`.  More information can be found [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @BradleyUffner that was the most prominent example on my mind that kept me from speaking in absolutes.