# Do we need to adhere to the Open-Closed Principle if we have good test coverage?

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

Why [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) is such a big deal?
If you have tests why you should worry about code modifications?

Comment: The open-closed principle is about preventing sweeping changes. Even if you have every part of your application covered with tests, that doesn't mean that you can easily add or change your code base. A recent client of mine had a code base that had a very high percentage of code coverage, but making changes was still really painful. One of the reasons was that even small feature requests lead to large ripples through the system (an OCP violation). This was in many cases so costly, that management sometimes decided to cancel such feature request.

Comment: @Steven maybe lead to large ripples was because of Single Responsibility principle violation and not Open-Closed principle? Why do you think it was only because OCP violation?

Comment: Is wasn't only an open/closed principle violation. It was the complete SOLID package actually. Those principles are never violated in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have tests why you should worry about code modifications?

In the context of  unit testing, the  *open-closed* principle is a design principle that allows you to add new code with minimal impact on code that has already been written before hand. What has been tested will not be changed because of new requirements, thus reducing the area of damage a programmer can create over a stable code base. Consider the following pseudo object-oriented code example that does not follow the open-closed principle :

```
class NumberOperations {
   public void add(Number a,Number b) {
      Number result = null;
      if(a instanceof Integer && b instanceof Integer) {
         Integer aInt = (Integer)a;
         Integer bInt = (Integer)a;
         result = aInt + bInt;
      } else {
          //failure/error : only integer operations supported.
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

You test the above code and all works as expected. You now decide to support decimal operations as well so you modify the `add` function as follows :

```
public void add(Number a,Number b) {
    Number result = null;
    if(a instanceof Integer && b instanceof Integer) {
        Integer aInt = (Integer)a;
        Integer bInt = (Integer)a;
        result = aInt + bInt;
    } else if(a instanceof Double && b instanceof Double) {
        Double aDecimal = (Double)a;
        Double bDecimal = (Double)b;
        result = aDecimal + bDecimal ;
    } else {
      //failure/error : only integer and double operations supported.
    }
    return result;
}
```

With just one new simple requirement of supporting decimal addition, you have added 4 new lines of code, rearranged one line of code and doubled your area of damage. This may look trivial with such a simple example but real world code is seldom this basic. You may introduce side-effects to existing code that none of the test cases can fathom.

If you adhered to the *open-closed* principle, you could have subclasses called `IntegerOperations` and `DoubleOperations` extending from `NumberOperations` (which could now be abstract) that implement the `add` method. The code inside the first `if` in the `add` method shown above could be moved to the `add` method in `IntegerOperations` class and the code in the `else-if` could be moved to the `add` method in `DoubleOperations` class. If your language supports generics, you could even get rid of the type checks that the above example shows.

You then test out these two new classes individually. When you get a requirement to add two `String`s, you create a new class called `StringOperations`. You don't have to worry about any unwanted changes being made to `IntegerOperations` or `DoubleOperations` and therefore don't have to test them again. You only need to test the `StringOperations` class.

**In Summary** :  OCP not only reduces the area of damage that you may expose your codebase to but also allows users of your API to add new functionality (via subclassing for example) without the need to rely on you for making these changes. You may be able to ensure all critical code paths are tested without OCP. What you can't protect your codebase from is the risk of someone else breaking code that has already been tested which introduces a bug you have not even accounted for in your tests.

Comment: So, with OCP you should not call a static method directly but to have an interface, do I understand you correct? Even if for 90% of classes will be only only one implementation of interface, so, we double the work.

Comment: What if IntegerOperations will have some operation that are not allowed for StringOperations?

Comment: @Romper I am not sure why you are trying to find the relation between *OCP* and `static` methods. I also don't understand what you mean by *Even if for 90% of classes will be only only one implementation of interface, so, we double the work*. If `InegerOperations` has operations not present for `StringOperations`, then you violate LSP. To adhere to LSP in this case you could use composition for the additional behavior (For example by using the [Strategy Pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203210/is-context-inheritance-as-shown-by-head-first-design-patterns-duck-example-ir)

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world you would have tests which cover 100% of the code base and you could also measure that by using tools. However, neither of those are true. Getting 100% coverage and making sure that 100% coverage still works when the application is five years old is very hard. You might not have the time required to achieve it before a release. You have some other persons on the team that isn't as strict. You might simply have a deadline that must be honored. Tools that show 100% typically understands that a code line have been reached by one execution branch while on another where it also can be reached have not been executed.

In a perfect world your code is also readable and easy to understand. In a real world the readability is not just dependent on you, but your entire team. It's also dependent on if you really can choose the best solution of every problem you get during the entire applications lifetime. I got 20 years of experience and I still find myself write shitty code now and then. The reason is that I'm not perfect and I do not always have perfect conditions like crystal clear requirements or a great description of what the customer wants.

The SOLID principles and other best practices and principles help you since the world is not perfect. But by following principles like Open/Closed principle you give your future self a much better chance of dealing with your code base. Those principles have been defined by experienced people who have learned the hard way what works and what not.

Comment: But if your code is not tested, if you don't have guarantees that it works properly, how you can close the code from modifications?

Comment: Sigleton also was a pattern, and now it is an anti-pattern, maybe tests make OCP an anti-pattern?

Comment: O/C isn't about bugs. O/C is about preventing future changes driven by changed requirements.

Comment: Singleton is not an anti-pattern. It still have it's use cases just as service locator do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of posts like that. They typically demonstrate some narrow use cases and use that as a proof of that there are no valid use cases. I'm simply saying that there are. If you are aware of the negative consequences but still think it's the best solution, go ahead and use it. i.e. i'm not a fan of absolute rules. I'm for guidelines and pragmatic approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you have really really good system tests you can be confident your code still works even with big, principle-breaking edits, so despite what some principle fanatics would have you think, the principle isn't a necessity - but it is a practicality. You don't have to use it, but you'll generally make things easier for yourself if you do.
The helpful practicality with the O/C principle is being able to extend existing code to meet new requirements without risking breaking existing uses of that code. Even if you don't end up needing to spend time fixing existing code because the edits didn't break it, you'd still need to retest it.

When considering the existing tests (and I feel this applies more to unit tests here than system tests) you've got to consider whether edits that go against the closed part of the o/c principle will break or invalidate existing tests. If you break existing tests with a change of interface or a change of required pre-condition you can't truly use the same tests on both the old and new implementations (your new tests may be based on the old but wont be exactly the same). Perhaps more worrying (just because it won't make itself obvious like broken tests will) is that the edits may mean that there should be some additional tests that aren't already there - maybe you've introduced new special cases. The edits might have unintended side effects that are not tested for.

Ultimately the O/C principle has to just be an aim, with some principles we can tell for sure whether we have successfully followed them. With the O/C principle we might discover that when we actually want to extend it, the original is not as open as we'd hoped, and if it turns out the original didn't work properly its going to need changing even if you think this goes against the closedness.

Like many principles it's not that it's essential it's that in general it's helpful and the effort to follow it will pay off over time.

Comment: How O/C make things easier, do you have an example?

Comment: The easier part is about future edits - not the original code. Any place you want to be able to re-use existing functionality, but extended to be slightly different but you don't want to spend effort on checking/changing existing uses of the code. The open part makes things easier because you can reuse the code. The closed part makes it easier because its easier if you don't need to worry about breaking other things. So a bit to general to give a more specific example

Comment: Another case where following it helps vs not following it is that if the extended code is not aware of its extensions - and they are not aware of each other, you reduce the cross dependencies on the code (which again is not essential just helps with maintenance). Contrast that to the code smell where instead of extending a base implementation separately a switch of all possible extended uses ends up in the common code. A new case gets added whenever there is a new extension and with it new dependencies.