# Is it good approach to use Singleton for Driver instance?

Tags: c#, selenium, singleton

Please consider this approach:

```
public class Driver
{
    public static IWebDriver Instance;
    public static IJavaScriptExecutor iJavaScriptExecutor;

    public static IWebDriver getInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = new ChromeDriver(GetGoogleChromeDriverPath());
            iJavaScriptExecutor = Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        }

        return Instance;
    }

    static string GetGoogleChromeDriverPath()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Is it good approach to use Singleton for Driver instance ?

Edit:

```
public sealed class Driver
{
    private Driver() { }

    public static IWebDriver Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

    private class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested() { }

        internal static readonly IWebDriver instance = new ChromeDriver(GetGoogleChromeDriverPath());
    }

    static string GetGoogleChromeDriverPath()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    }
}
```

So as `Zohar Peled` suggested i change it to this version.
How can i add `IJavaScriptExecutor` instance to my class ?

Comment: Almost *never* it is a good idea to use a *Singleton*. That is why some consider it an [anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: Any other options ?

Comment: This is a poor implementation of the singelton design pattern. [Read this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) by Jon Skeet and adopt a better one.

Comment: Any recommended version ?

Comment: Yes. The version where you read the article and make up your own opinion, or just do what Jon said.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: You can cast IWebdriver to IJavaScriptExecutor safely. (IJavaScriptExecutor)Instance.ExecuteScript(ScriptGoesHere);

Comment: As for your initial question about a singleton being a good idea, personally, I perter to use dependency injection. You would register an instance of the driver (So, still technically a singleton) that is injected into the constructor of any other class that requires it. Here's an example that could get you started: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection