# How can one make two instances of this Singleton Class?

Tags: c++, oop, object, singleton

This code should be enough for restricting only one instance of singleton class. How can we make two instances of this object?

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton()
    {}
    ~Singleton()
    {}
    static Singleton * ptr;
public:
    static Singleton * CreateObject()
    {
        if (!ptr)
            ptr = new Singleton;
        return ptr;
    }
    static void freeObject()
    {
        if (ptr)
        {
            delete ptr;
            ptr = 0;
        }
    }
};
Singleton * Singleton::ptr = 0;
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to rethink your design (assuming this isn't an academic exercise). Perhaps share with us why you'd need 2 instances of something that is designed to only need 1?

Comment: the whole purpose (which in itself is questionable) of a singleton is to allow only a single instance. Why do you want to have two of them? Can you change the class?

Comment: Your first sentence literally said it's impossible

Comment: @PasserBy I read the "should" as the mark of doubt.

Comment: @YSC The question doesn't make more sense even if that were the case

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern is about **not** having two instances of a class.

The easiest way to get rid of that constraint... is to **remove** the singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton
{
};

Singleton one = new Singleton();
Singleton two = new Singleton();
```

As a side-effect, you just made your code cleaner, too, as [Singleton is considered an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern) by many.

Answer (score 1):

Well, another possibility not yet exposed is the cuncurrency.
That singleton pattern is not secure enough.
If you have two (or more) different threads calling simultaneously the `CreateObject()` method they could easily get different instances of the object.

You should add a mutex to secure that pattern.
Or move to another pattern like this one:

```
 static Singleton& instance()
 {
   static Singleton INSTANCE;
   return INSTANCE;
 }
```

Answer (score -4):

> This code should be enough for restricting only one instance of singleton class.

It is not.

> How can we make two instances of this object?

With the singleton implementation you gave in your question, it is fairly easy to create a second instance:

```
Singleton* s1 = Singleton::CreateObject();
Singleton* s2 = new Singleton(*s1);
```

And enjoy memory leaks.

---

To fix your singleton, you should respect the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (if you define at least one constructor, define all five of them). Or you could use something else than a singleton.

Comment: If you doubt me: please see [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8e8c4efe8671a5c).

Comment: I didn't downvote. I think the answer strictly correct, but ill-advised.