# Using a trait constructor

Tags: php, pdo, constructor, static, singleton

I have a class which I am going to make Singleton. For this reason, I want to use a trait. Something like this:

```
trait TSingleton
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}

    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class Db implements IDb
{
    use TSingleton;
    ...
}
```

The question is if the Db's constructor would be private also, and if it does, why could I create its inheritors?

Comment: why not [testing it](https://3v4l.org/5kc4s)? (spoiler: it's private too) But [you can override it](https://3v4l.org/WPG5o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern Is probably worth a read.