# Is it possible to inherit a singleton class with a base class (non-singleton class). If yes, is it a good practice?

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I am actually trying to implement something where a singleton class would extend a non-singleton class.

I've tried reading multiple answers but none of them answer my question.

```java
class Parent{
    // Code goes here
}

class MySingleton extends Parent{
    // Code goes here
}
```

I have 2 questions now.

1) Is this possible in java/kotlin?

2) If yes, is it a good practice? Please provide some reference.

Comment: 1) Yes. Why wouldn't it be? 2) No, [singleton is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: 1) yes 2) it greatly depends

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is this possible in java?

Yes, but.

It depends how you implement your singleton. Singleton has become more of an anti-pattern over the years, and when you still use it, then it is good practice to use **enums**:

```
public enum SomeSingleton { 
  INSTANCE;
  ...
```

which of course: doesn't work when you want to extend a parent class.

> 2) If yes, is it a good practice? Please provide some reference.

As said, singleton alone is (mostly) regarded bad practice these days. So adding *another* constraint sure doesn't make things better.

Conceptually, it sounds wrong. What if someone does this:

```
List<Parent> someInstances = Arrays.asList(parentInstanceA, parentInstanceB, thatSingletonInstanceOfMySingleton);
```

All of a sudden, you have multiple things that of course aren't exactly the same, but well, they all go into that list nicely.

Long story short: I wouldn't do it. If at all, use an **enum**, and then consider to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @VrajeshHirani I appreciate the quick and kind response, too!