# Share data across tabs & VCs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a custom tab bar controller, and a data model powered by a stateController. I want to share data from my model across the tabs.

**Few callouts:**

- My app uses both storyboards & programmatic (Swift 5). Assume storyboard here
- When the app loads, I check userDefaults to see if it's the first app launch. If it is, firstTimeVC is the rootVC
- If it's not, my Tab Bar is the rootVC. And this logic lives in the Scene Delegate

I'm using Dependency Injection to create a shared instance of my data model across tabs. People suggest injecting the data model into my TabBar & childVCs using the App / Scene Delegate. Problem is, the TabBar isn't always the rootVC.

**My questions are:**

- Can I inject my data model into the TabBar's child VCs directly from the TabBar? Instead of the Scene Delegate?
- If I use Scene Delegate, then how do I inject the data model into the TabBar's childVCs when the TabBar is NOT the rootVC (ie first app launch)
- Or should the TabBar always be the rootVC, and I move the first-launch-check to a childVC instead of Scene Delegate
- What's the right way to do this?

My first time app launch check (currently inside Scene Delegate):

```
  if isFirstLaunch {
     rootViewController = "FirstTimeUserViewController"
  } else {
     rootViewController = "TabBarController"
  }

window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My dependency injection (currently inside Scene Delegate):

```
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomTabBarController") as! CustomTabBarController
for child in tabBarController.viewControllers ?? [] {
    if let top = child as? StateControllerProtocol {
        top.setStateController(stateController: stateController)
    }
}
```

A screenshot of my storyboard & VC setup:

[image: Screenshot of my storyboard & VC setup]

Comment: why not create the data model in the app delegate and access it with a singleton?

Comment: singleton's generally make code less re-usable. and increase coupling and dependency between my VCs, App Delegate and models. they're considered an 'anti-pattern' in Swift for this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12755539/13551385

Comment: In this case your data model is already a global and, as you describe it, already creates a  coupling between VCs. Singletons should be avoided when they cause coupling, not when it's already there. VCs are already almost never reusable with different data anyway.