# Global Variables in Dart: Singleton versus Static

Tags: flutter, dart

When you want to define global variables in Dart to be read and written anywhere within your program, the general advice seems to be create a Singleton class, e.g.

```
class Globals {
    // Constructor boilerplate
    static final Globals _instance = Globals._();
    factory Globals() => _instance;
    Globals._();

    // Global variable
    int variable = 0;
}
```

You can then read the value using `Globals().variable` and write using `Globals().variable = 1`.

However the same seems to be possible with a simple static variable, e.g.

```
class Globals {
    // Global variable
    static int variable = 0;
}
```

Which are read and written using `Globals.variable` and `Globals.variable = 1`. If we run a simple example:

```
void main() {
   print(Globals.variable);
   Globals.variable++;
   print(Globals.variable);
}
```

It returns

```
0
1
```

And so seems to be functioning as a global variable. I'm using globals in the context of Flutter, where I want a collection of variables to be widely available and adjustable throughout the app.

So what is the difference between declaring globals using singletons and statics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globals are not good programming, someone should have taught that in the basic course and Singleton is not much better. It's just a fancier way of declaring globals. See [Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern).

So the literal answer to your question is "nothing of importance". Global variables and Singletons are basically the same, with the same problems.

The actual answer to such a question should be **use neither!!!**

If you don't know how to manage your programs state without it, go read up on [state management in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).