# add "std::mutex" as a member field into an only-movable class without manually code "move constructor" (std::unique_ptr<> is ugly)

Tags: c++, c++17, mutex, move

By design, class `B` is uncopiable but movable.

Recently, I **enjoy** that `B` has **automatically**-generated move constructor and move assignment operator.

Now, I add `std::mutex` to class `B`.
The problem is that `std::mutex` can't be moved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
class C{
    public: C(){}
    public: C(C&& c2){ }
    public: C& operator=(C&& c2){ return *this; }
    //: by design, I don't allow copy, can only move
};
class B{public: int a=0;
    C c;
    //------ 10+ trivial fields ---
    //private: std::mutex mutexx;  //<=== uncomment = uncompilable
};
int main(){
   B b1;
   B b2;
   b1=std::move(b2);
}
```

Is there a solution to make it compile?

### My poor workaround 1 (manual)

Manually create 2 move functions.

```
class B{public: int a=0;
    C c;
    //------ 10+ trivial fields ---
    private: std::mutex mutexx;
    public: B(B&& b2){
         this->c=std::move(b2.c); 
         //--- copy other trivial fields (long and hard to maintain) --
         //:: intentionally omit move/copy of mutex
    }
    public: B& operator=(B&& b2){ ... }
};
```

This workaround creates the effect that I want.

### My poor workaround 2 (unique_ptr)

Use `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>`, but there are 3 minor disadvantages :-

1. Very ugly
2. Add a bit of extra heap & cpu cost.  The cost might be little, but I will resent it forever.
3. I also need to refactor some of my code from `mutexx.lock()` to `mutexx->lock()`

### Edit : My poor workaround 3 (encapsulate mutex)

(Add after get the first answer)

Encapsulate `std::mutex` into a new class, and create 2 move functions that do nothing.

If future reader may use this approach, beware that my question itself is questionable.
Thank  "ALX23z" and "j6t" for warning.

Comment: There's a reason why `std::mutex` is not movable. Say, one thread locks it and another moves it. How should it behave? Trying to move an object with a mutex, or even with a dynamically allocated mutex (say, via `std::unique_ptr`) is an easy way to find yourself in various data-races and UB. Consider using thread safety libraries like `libguarded` or store classes with mutexes only via some smart pointers.

Comment: @ALX23z ::   In my use case, I want to ignore such problem. (my poor workaround 1 implies that).   If it ever happen, I am ok with undefined behavior.   Thank, I will look into libguarded. ^^

Comment: The design is questionable. If the mutex protects something in the instances of `B`, `b1` and `b2`, how do you guarantee that the protection in `b1` is upheld at the time when `b2` is moved over to `b1`? The only reasonable solution is to have a move assignment operator in `B` that guarantees the protection protocol. From the design perspective, it does not make a lot of sense to depend on the compiler-generated move assingment operator.

Comment: Note that you don't have to keep repeating `public:`. An access declaration applies to every name that comes after it, until there's another access declaration.

Comment: @Pete Becker  :: You are right.  Thank.  It is my bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I enjoy that B has automatically-generated move constructor

Why don't rename `class B` and use it as a base class?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
class C{
    public: C(){}
    public: C(C&& c2){ }
    public: C& operator=(C&& c2){ return *this; }
    //: by design, I don't allow copy, can only move
};
class B1{public: int a=0;
    C c;
    //------ 10+ trivial fields ---
};

class B : public B1 {
    public: B& operator=(B&& b2){ return *this; }
    private: std::mutex mutexx;
};

int main(){
   B b1;
   B b2;
   b1=std::move(b2);
}
```

Comment: This answer is useful.  Thank.   It is just my feeling, but I still wish that I don't need chunky feature like inheritance for this little thing.

Comment: If you do not want it, you can place B1 in the inside `class B { B1 b1;
    public: B& operator=(B&& b2){ return *this; }
    private: std::mutex mutexx;
};`. There is no other simpler ways.

Comment: BTW using `std::mutex` unique in each object is a bad practice. Consider using `static std::shared_mutex B::mutexx;`

Comment: :: thank, I never heard that such practice is a bad practice.  ^^

Comment: I would not say it is bad practice. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @j6t Your comment sounds strange taking into account your comment to the question.

Comment: @273K I'd say the opposite, using a static mutex is a bad practice unless you write a singleton.

Comment: @ALX23z Singleton is an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: @273K decide, either using a singleton is bad practice or not. Cause static mutex is effectively a singleton.