# Get async object from module exactly once

Tags: python

I have module serv.py:

```
async def init_serv():
    serv = Serv()
    return await serv.init_with_params()
```

(of course, this is an abbreviated version)

In other modules I am doing:

```
from serv import init_serv

serv = init_serv()
```

This works fine, but whenever I import this module it creates a new instance of it.

I would like to have one instance, so if it wasn't asynchronous I could do that:

serv.py:

```
async def init_serv():
    serv = Serv()
    return await serv.init_with_params()

serv = init_serv()
```

and in other modules:

```
from serv import serv
```

But this obviously doesn't work because I'm calling an asynchronous function outside the async function.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for a singleton pattern.(which is somehow an anti pattern but not in this situation)

[Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)

[What are drawbacks or disadvantages of singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-are-drawbacks-or-disadvantages-of-singleton-pattern)

```
class ClssNme:

    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(ClssNme, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
```

Comment: If this is anti pattern then what is better?

Comment: it's quite a popular pattern but it's controversial. it depends on the project. in this situation it's totally fine i think.