# Singleton Inheritance - Which object is created?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, singleton

I've created two classes - a base class and derived class where the base class is a singleton.

When I call the derived class constructor, which object is being created as the static instance? Is it a base class object or derived one, and why?

As

```
#include <iostream>
class Singleton {
protected:
    static Singleton* instance;
    Singleton() {}
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
Singleton* Singleton::instance= nullptr;;

class DerivedSingleton : public Singleton {
public:
int x;
    static DerivedSingleton* getInstance() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new DerivedSingleton();
        }
        return (DerivedSingleton*)instance;
    }
};
int main(){
    Singleton *instance = DerivedSingleton::getInstance();
    std::cout << sizeof(DerivedSingleton) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(*instance) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(Singleton) << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
4
1
1
```

I tried printing the values of the sizes but i cant connect why the base class object is being created.

Comment: Base class ctor are autmatically called before entering  the body of the derived class ctor if you don't use them in the initializer list of the derived class.

Comment: If you want to create a "singleton" base-class I recommend you look into [the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). And for singletons in general in C++, use [the Meyers singleton](https://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html).

Comment: [Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: As for your problem, you only have a pointer to the `Singleton` part of the object you create. With your code, you need to cast `instance` each time you want to use any functionality from `DerivedSingleton`.

Comment: Also note that it's possible to create copies of your singleton objects. You need to forbid that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks! that makes sense. appreciate the help.

Comment: @GauravMehta Your singleton is not thread safe.  It is possible that multiple copies of the singleton can be created if two or more threads call `getInstance()`.

Comment: Before going into all the details of correctness of your implementation. Needing a singleton is in a lot of cases a design problem which will negatively impact the (unit)testability and scalabillity/maintainability of your project. Whatever you do do, do NOT use `new` to return an instance of your singleton. Use the Meyer's singleton pattern. `auto& Instance() { static Singleton instance; return instance; }`. At least that will have threadsafe initialization and the singletons destructor will get called at program shutdown

Comment: Another solution is that you learn about abstract baseclasses, and dependency injection. Create an instance of you class in main and inject the abstract baseclass into code that needs access to the data/behavior provided by your singleton.

Comment: You seem to be confusing static type with [dynamic type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Dynamic_type). The dynamic type of the object pointed to by `instance` is `DerivedSingleton`. This is the polymorphic type of the object as observed by which `virtual` member gets called (it if had any). The static type of the object is whatever type dereferencing the pointer yields as observed by the type system. The static type is always `Singleton` in this case. `sizeof` is compile time constant, `sizeof(*instance)` gives you the size of the static type, not of the dynamic type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int a;
};

struct bar : foo {
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(foo) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(bar) << "\n";

    foo* f;
    bar* b;
    std::cout << sizeof(*f) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(*b) << "\n";
}
```

[Possible output is](https://godbolt.org/z/KxoeWPY5z):

```
4
8
4
8
```

`foo* f` is a pointer to a `foo`. Dereferencing it yields a `foo`, not a `bar`. Hence, in your code `sizeof(*instance)` is effectively `sizeof(Singleton)`.

---

Your Singleton design has various flaws.

`Singleton` can be copied:

```
Singleton a_copy = *Singleton::getInstance();
Singleton another_copy = a_copy;
```

`DerivedSingleton` has a public default constructor and can be copied too:

```
DerivedSingleton a;
DerivedSingleton b;
DerivedSingleton c = b;
```

And because the default constructor does not use `Singleton::getInstance()` but the protected constructor `Singleton()`, the two instances `a` and `b` each have their own distinct subobject of type `Singleton`. That's a whole lot of instances for something that should allow only one ;).

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G58dcYEdh)

As mentioned in comments, things get worse when you use this with multiple threads, because your `getInstance()` is not thread-safe. You should read about the Meyer Singleton. It isn't the holy grail, though once you understood what it achieves and why you can still decide to use something else. For a base class that turns the derived into a singelton you can consider CRTP. Ordinary inheritance doesn't play that well with singleton-ness (merely making the constructor protected is not sufficient as illustrated with examples above).

Answer (score -1):

Only one object is created, which is of type DerivedSingleton. This is because DerivedSingleton::getInstance() is called, and it ensures that only one instance of DerivedSingleton exists throughout the program.

Comment: *and it ensures that only one instance of DerivedSingleton exists throughout the program* -- In a multithreaded program, this will not be true.  The singleton that the OP coded is not thread safe, and two or more instances of `DerivedSingleton` could be created if two or more threads enter the `getInstance` function "at the same time".

Comment: even with a single thread, it is not clear what you mean with "it ensures that only one instance ..." The class has a public default constructor and you can create as many instances of it as you like. Its not a singleton