# singleton allows to create static instances But does this increase the response time?

Tags: java, singleton

The singleton mechanism helps us to create an instance which is static in nature. But when using it in a network environment ie; when more than one client is using the application, does this makes the system slower by blocking the creation of new instances.

Comment: can anyone tell me why i got this negative marking on this question so that i can correct next time.

Comment: It's nominated for closure as 'primarily opinion based', which it is: what slows down a system is a function of many things, not just whether some instance of some object is a singleton. Whether in your case it's a problem is undiagnosable with the provided information - and thus answers will merely be opinions. 

Note that by the nature of a singleton, having one will not 'block' other code pathways from using it. All pathways in the same execution environment will merely be referencing the same underlying bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this makes the system slower by blocking the creation of new
>   instances.

I don't think so. Singleton only allows one instance per application domain. So if the new instance is not created, existing instance will be returned. *(Other thing that should be taken into consideration with respect to singleton would be **thread safety**.)*

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would like to know more about singleton can you suggest me any tutorials..??

Comment: @Dileep, See:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html and You may see also this question for [Singleton Anti Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448393/singleton-design-pattern-pitfalls) and