# Singleton object destroy in jar but work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I make singleton class and use this class object in different class this code work fine in eclipse
but when i make runnable jar than it take empty hashmap list i don't know why my code...

My singleton class

```
public class PointCalculate {

  public HashMap<String, Float> calPoint;
  private static PointCalculate instance;

  private PointCalculate(){
     calPoint = new HashMap<String, Float>();
  }

  public static PointCalculate getInstance(){
     if(instance==null){
        instance = new PointCalculate();
     }
     return instance;
  }

  public void calculatePoint(String uid ,float point){

     Float ps = instance.calPoint.get(uid);
     if(ps==null) {
        ps = point;
        instance.calPoint.put(uid, ps);
     }
     else {
        ps = point+ps.floatValue();
        instance.calPoint.put(uid, ps);
     }
  }
}
```

and i am passing value from this class below....

```
  public class Exp {

     public void setpoint(){
        PointCalculate obj = PointCalculate.getInstance();
        obj.calculatePoint(rowkey, point);//rowkey and point come from file.....
     }
  }
```

now i am passing hashmap....

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     PointCalculate obj = PointCalculate.getInstance();
     SqlInsertPoint.givePoint(obj.calPoint);
  }
```

but in SqlInsertPoint.givePoint() hashmap list will be empty i don't know why if any body know than help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, my first thought is that your factory method is not thread safe, so you cannot guarantee that your object is a singleton.

Comment: @Aurand please give me some hint i am not getting because i have never work in thread and i am not using any thread method

Comment: @RishiDwivedi Are you calling the Exp.setPoint before calling the SqlInsertPoint.givePoint? 
If not then this is your issue. Singleton does not save data automatically on disk. So every time the Singleton object will be disposed (every time your program terminates), you will lose it state and the information it holds in memory. If you need to save your data, then you need to save it to the disk (using DB, serialization, so on..) before the termination of the program.

Comment: private final static PointCalculate instance= new PointCalculate(); <- would be a little bit more thread safe.

Comment: This might be due the issue with program execution flow.Please make sure execution is sequential and only single instance of PointCalculate is created by adding some log.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this code? In `main` you obtain an instance of PointCalculate, do not put any points into it, and pass it over to `givePoint` method. Since you didn't populate the HashMap, it should be empty.

On a separate note, static Singletons are difficult to get right, and in general should be avoided ([couple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448561/2517807) [good reasons](http://google.com/search?q=singleton%20anitpattern)). In your concrete case not only `PointCalculate` class is not thread-safe, but it also exposes `calPoint` to the whole world. So, anybody can run the following code and essentially override your instance.

> PointCalculate.getInstance().calPoint = new HashMap();