# One ArrayList for all classes

Tags: java, arraylist, global-variables

I want to have one list for accessing from any class. But when I try to reach a list from another class it throws NullPointerException. I tried to solve it with constructors, but in this case every class which have an object of the main class (where the list stores) create a new list by calling constuctor. But I need unique list which can be accessed, modified and etc. from other classes. How could I manage this?

Comment: You'd probably start to manage this by providing some more information, e.g. a [mcve]. Currently I have no idea what you're actually after or which problems you try to solve - some sort of code is very likely to clarify it.

Comment: so you´re looking for a `static` `List`?

Comment: Look for keywords like: static, singleton 
Make a try and when you then still have problem, post some code and we can help you

Comment: Just be careful when designing around singletons.  They are [often considered an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448407/6902543) when testing your code.

Comment: So what's the difference between singleton pattern and static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. I just needed to declare my ArrayList `static`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Use the concept of Singleton class.

```
class List
{
    private static ArrayList<int> intlist;
    private static List list;

    //private constructor [singleton class]
    private List(){
       intlist==new ArrayList<int>();
    };

    private static List getList()
    { 
       if(this.list==null)
          list=new List();

       return list;
    }

    public getIntList(){return this.intlist;}
}

class A
{
    public void Test()
    {
        List l=List.getList();
        l.getIntList().add(1);
    }
}

class B
{
    public void Test()
    {
        List l=List.getList();
        l.getIntList().add(2);
    }
}
```

Now class A and class B are getting same list to put value into it.